# Null on Foreign Key

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two tables : Invoice_stat and PMLprojects.

EER Diagram :
Invoice_stat
- invoice_id INT(11)
- other fields

PMLProjects
-id int(11)
- other fields

Relation :
Invoice_stat
Name : PMLProjects
Count : One
Ownership : blank

Name : Invoice_stat
Count : Many
Ownership : blank

(sorry, I want to put picture actually, but I need more reputation to put picture :)

One project sometime have many Invoice, because it's invoice generated monthly.

When I check on table, it show foreign_key on invoice_stat table.

```
CREATE TABLE `Invoice_stat` (
 `Invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `EmailStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `PaidStatus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `Invoice_Number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `DateCreate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `PMLprojects_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Invoice_id`),
 KEY `PMLprojects_fk` (`PMLprojects_fk`),
 CONSTRAINT `Invoice_stat_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PMLprojects_fk`) REFERENCES `PMLprojects` (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=190145 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

but, when I check on PMLproject table, no foreign key.

My problem is, when I create record in Invoice_stat, with click a button, it always show NULL on Invoice_stat table (PMLprojects_fk).

To create table on Invoice_stat, I use script on server :

```
function createCaseStatusWithItem() {
 // Automatically number todo lists for the user.
 var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
 lock.waitLock(10000);
 var query = app.models.Invoice_stat.newQuery();
 var allTodoLists = query.run();
 var todoList = app.models.Invoice_stat.newRecord();
 now = new Date();

todoList.Invoice_id;
 todoList.Invoice_Number = allTodoLists.length + 1;
 todoList.EmailStatus = "Yes";
 todoList.PaidStatus = "No";
 todoList.DateCreate = now;

 app.saveRecords([todoList]);
 lock.releaseLock();

 }
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Your server function is missing the part where you assign the foreign record. How are you passing/linking the relevant record in your PMLprojects table? Also in regards to tables in AM the FK is only shown on the many side of a one-to-many relation.

Comment: Invoice_id|int(11)|NO|PRI|NULL|auto_increment|
EmailStatus|varchar(255)|YES| |NULL||
PaidStatus|varchar(255)|YES| |NULL||
Invoice_Number|int(11)|YES||NULL||
DateCreate|datetime|YES||NULL||
PMLprojects_fk|int(11)|YES|MUL|NULL||

Comment: Do you have example, how to assign foreign record to a table ?  <br>

Comment: I would need to know more detail about your setup. For one why are you using server function vs just a form widget? How do you even know which project to assign this to, is there a matching field between tables? Usually you would query the other model in your server function or just fetch the other record that you want to relate it to using app.models.YourOtherModel.getRecord(id) and then set todolist.YourRelation = OtherRecord; but from your info it’s hard to say how the relation is supposed to be assigned.

Comment: First page will go to PMLproject table list, once in click on one project, it will display project detail, there is invoice button there, but it will click when project finished. So Invoice not created yet. Someday finance staff will click on invoice button on project detail, it will generate invoice number, entry data into invoice_stat table and send email. So, one button to do all work, so I put it on server function. I though, when this button already in project detail, means it already related between Invoice_stat table and PMLproject.

Comment: Actually since you are calling a custom server function from the button presumably via google.script.run the relation information does not get passed unless you include it as a parameter in the function call. The only time this works is if you use createItem() in the client and your datasource is set to ‘PML_project: Invoice_stat (relation) (create)’ or your datasource is set to ‘Invoice_stat’ to manually assign project via datasource.item.PML_project = projectItem and then call createItem().

Comment: Hi Markus, If I change not using Server-Client, but direct to write script on button, Is it possible? I already try this, but still Invoice_stat.PMLprojects_fk still null.

Comment: Can you update the question on how you went about doing this?

Comment: On botton, I create script to create record : var myProjectList = app.datasources.PMLprojects;
var myProjectListID = myProjectList.Id;
var myDatasource = app.datasources.Invoice_stat;
var myCreateDatasource = myDatasource.modes.create;
now = new Date();

var draft = myDatasource.modes.create.item;
 draft.EmailStatus = "Yes";
 draft.PaidStatus = "No";
 draft.Invoice_Number = draft.id;
 draft.DateCreate = now;
 
 myCreateDatasource.createItem(function(newRecord) {
   var key = newRecord._key;
});